# How to iterate in double for loops in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I want to just take first elements from token1_list and token2_list in 1st iteration, 2nd elements in 2nd iteration. Currently in 1st iteration, it is taking all the elements from my lists, is there way to solve this?

```
char_list = []
for i in line_list:
    case1test = case1[int(i)-1]
    case1test1 = case1test.split()
    [char_list.append(case1test1[int(a):int(b)+1]) for a in token1_list for b in token2_list]
```

Comment: because you are explicitely iterating over both in your list comprehension? As an aside, **never use side effects in list comprehensions**. I.e. don't use `.append`, that is a mutator method. stick to pure functions in list comprehensions

Comment: Please read [ask] and try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like you are simply looking for `zip`...? What do the lists look like and what's your expected result?

Comment: not clear why you're using comprehension here. seems like `char_list.append` would suffice as well.